# boost pool: can I wean it from boost system?

Tags: c++, boost

The documentation for `pool` in 1.53.0 claims that it is 'header-only'. However, a minimal program:

```
#include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

ends up with undefined symbols from `boost_system`, and `bcp` thinks that `boost_system` is required. Is there `#define` or something to cure this?

Comment: Do you need threading support? If not, could you try to define `BOOST_POOL_NO_MT`?

Comment: And that would be `boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp` I guess …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known bug. https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7085.

- If you don't need multi-threading, we could
  modify `pool/detail/mutex.hpp` to *not* to include `<boost/thread/mutex.hpp>` as described in the URL,

  ```
  ...
  #if defined(BOOST_HAS_THREADS) && !defined(BOOST_NO_MT) && !defined(BOOST_POOL_NO_MT) 
  #include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
  #endif
  ...
  ```
- or, if you can't modify the files, fake the compiler that `<boost/thread/mutex.hpp>` has been defined:

  ```
  #define BOOST_POOL_NO_MT       // disable multi-threading
  #define BOOST_THREAD_MUTEX_HPP // define the #include-guard to disable the header

  #include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>

  int main () {}
  ```
- or, if you *do* need multi-threading, but C++11 is allowed, we could use `std::mutex` to substitute `boost::mutex`:

  ```
  #define BOOST_THREAD_MUTEX_HPP
  #include <mutex>
  namespace boost {
      using std::mutex;
  }

  #include <boost/pool/pool_alloc.hpp>

  int main () {}
  ```